# Which file shutil copy method to use in python to copy certain files from one folder to another?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io, copy

I would like to copy multiple files from one folder to another folder in python. To do this, there are several methods in shutil library that can do the job.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html

These methods are `copyfileobj(), Copyfile(), Copy(), Copy2()` and maybe more that I have left out. I am at a loss which one to use. For my simple job of of copying multiple files from one folder to another folder in Windows 10, which is the most appropriate method? Or makes no difference?

I am using Windows 10, python ver3.

Comment: Depends on what data types you have and what you want to do with them.  Some of those functions take file-like objects, some take file names (strings).  Some can copy a file into a directory, some copy only to a specific filename.  Some preserve metadata, some don't.

Comment: The documentation you linked explains the differences pretty clearly. For your simple job, the choices probably `copy2` if you want to copy metadata, or `copy` if you want fresh metadata. For example, do you want the file's last modification time to show the time you copied the file (use `copy`), or the time you saved the original file (use `copy2`)? Also, you don't want any of the ones that take a file object (something you got back from `open`) instead of a filename.

Comment: Meanwhile, if, after reading the docs, you have a specific question about what you read, that might make a good question to ask here.

Comment: @abarnert, thanks for your comment. So, if my objective is to copy a file and preserve the original file's modification date, the choice is `copy2`, right?

Comment: Yes, `copy2` tries to keep as much metadata as possible from the original file, including the modification date.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple script to copy all the files from a specific directory to another directory .

```py
import os
import shutil

rootdir = 'D:/Abd/Image/'
copytodir = 'D:/TestImgs/'
rootfiles = os.listdir(rootdir)
for file in rootfiles:
    shutil.copy2(file, copytodir)
```